# Is it better to put affected version in the comments or the answer?

Tags: discussion

Suppose I asked a Rails question 3 years ago and got a good answer for Rails 2.  Since then, Rails 3 has a different way to solve the problem, so someone posts an answer more suited to Rails 3.  The Rails 2 answer is at the top because of its longer history.  (This is a very common occurrence, BTW.)

Some think that a comment linking to the other answer is all that is appropriate. However, I think the top of both answers should include a line that says "This is for Rails 2. Please see the answer from xxxx for Rails 3" and vice-versa.

Is appropriate to edit an answer just to mention framework/language/OS version as I mention above?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is appropriate to edit an answer just to mention framework/language/OS version as I mention above?

Yes, absolutely. This is the kind of information that should be seen *first*.